# Seeking opinions on the best CMS platform for designers and front end developers

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, designer, modx, textpattern

I have so far been a dedicated Wordpress user, but have been researching other CMS solutions of late, specifically, looking for something that could potentially allow me to EASILY convert an XHTML site into a CMS site for most projects.

I don't care for PHP - and find adding the appropriate tags to Wordpress a bit of a challenge. I am building fairly simple sites and simple blogs - I don't need a lot of extensibility.

I have heard good things about ModX and Textpattern and have today installed them on a localhost and started playing with them. Each has a bit of a learning curve, but I like what I see in terms of their tag codes (which looks a lot more like html than php).

I'd like to design websites where most pages are distinct from one another and don't necessarily have to fit into a template. I am looking for an automagical solution where I can directly input my html, css, javascript code into a CMS platform and it spits out my website exactly as I'd imagined it. Is this just a dream?

With so many solutions out there, just wondering about other web designer's and non-hardcore developers preferences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's like asking if ipod or blackberry or n900 or htc etc.
While there are vast differences in how it works under the hood, for the most part you can expect about the same functionality, and it comes down to the provider and a particular feature you prefer in one over the other. In this case instead of your carrier you need to worry about you host, whether they offer the php version required aand the database you need etc. But for most part, you should be fine.

Modx Evo requirements : http://modxcms.com/learn/general-requirements.html

Modx Revo requires: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Server+Requirements

TextPattern requirements: http://textpattern.com/about/119/system-requirements

I find this an important thing to start with, while my server can handle either, you never know what server your clients are running(there still are some old configurations out there)

I haven't used Revo much yet, but it looks like there are quite a few really nice enhancements. One of them is installing packages. Previously you have to create TVs snippets chunks, so installing a package wasn't always so straight forward.

Modx Evo however has the import html feature, where you can load put your html site in a folder set the tag that holds the content, and modx will automatically create and fill the resources(pages), pretty nifty, but I've only used it to see what it does :)

Modx lets you get away with not knowing any php, but as your requirements change, you might find yourself needing an extra feature of script that is easy to add. I've found that using modx for the past 2 years or so has vastly improved my php abilities because of these additional functions required.

While I haven't worked with textpattern much I do remember installing it and playing around, but it just wasn't love at first sight, like with modx.
I also think modx is pretty easy for clients to navigate with some minimal coaching, but that is more of a comparison with joomla and drupal etc.

Bottom line, I think few people have spent enough time with both to REALLY understand both in terms of differences/advantages and mostly what you'll get is "the one I use is better; evidence being me using it" (myself included) or worse yet "I see you're mentioning CMSes, here's my favorite one"

To wrap up, one more important aspect (and this one is really important if you don't know your way around backends and php much) the community. If you run into problems, how likely is the modx vs textpattern forum.community willing to help. A good indication is community size. While I can't see the numbers for textpattern, currently modx forums show "255 Guests, 46 Users (3 Hidden)"

good luck

Comment: Hello Daniel - thank you so much for your incredibly thoughtful response. While I do know that CMSs each offer unique advantages and disadvantages, depending upon one's skills, preferences and requirements, I'd not previously given much thought to the server-side of the equation. And what you're saying about ModX Evolution sounds a lot like what I'm looking for - which is an easier way to design a website, code it with xhtml/css, then implement a powerful CMS in the back which doesn't affect the design any more than is necessary. I guess I'm hoping to design something that looks wholly unique.

Comment: and then import it with relative ease into a development framework. I want the flexibility of being able to design in a way that doesn't broadcast the CMS it is situated on - which is not something I've found in working with Wordpress (though, that may be more of a skill-level thing). But you're the second person who has given ModX high praise (in addition to all I've seen in the forums), so will take a good hard look at it, too. I really appreciate your help with my question, Daniel.

Comment: I hope yo do :)
in addition you can have a look at these: http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2009/03/28/building-a-website-with-modx-for-newbies-part-1-introduction/  and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/working-with-a-content-management-framework-modx/

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with HTML then Textpattern's method of adding markup like tags into templates for content will probably be relatively straightforward for you to pick-up. The biggest issue most people seem to have in understanding Textpattern is its semantic model, there's a great page on [the semantic model on Textpattern's Textbook site](http://textpattern.net/wiki/index.php?title=Textpattern_Semantic_Model) that should help.

I'm a big fan of Textpattern for building simple but powerful small to medium sites that do not require complicated user groups. It's quick to build well designed sites and the admin interface is really simple.

The Textpattern community is extremely friendly and helpful if you ever need help. Best place to ask things is on the [Textpattern Forum](http://forum.textpattern.com/).

Comment: That's the one I'm going to take a crack at! I hear there's a big learning curve, but looking at the Textile code, it seems a lot more intuitive than PHP. It sounds like the development there is slower than, say WP, and I worry that with all the new CMS options available it might be on the wane? But I really admire some of the designer/developers who have talked about using it... Yep - I am going to take the plunge, then write about my experiences for anyone else who is considering it.

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, monkeyninja!

Comment: The community is smaller but definitely not inactive. There's a lot of plugins being developed and a couple of new core Textpattern releases being worked on. Will be interested to hear what you think of it and find the whole experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [sNews CMS](http://snewscms.com/) in addition to MODx/Textpattern. It is quite minimalistic

- PHP code is single file (excluding language translations).
- You need to import one SQL script on phpMyAdmin and you are set.

After that its only styling and content.

Comment: Cool - I'd not heard of that one. I'll check it out and get back to you! Thank you.